# How to SUM each table value of a data table

Tags: mysql

I have four table, and need to help with total sum every price in each table

1 Table skom

```
 _________________________________
 | id | noskom      | price_skom |
 |____|_____________|____________|
 |  1 | 1           |   10       | 
 |  2 | 2           |   30       |  
 |__3_|_3___________|___50_______|
```

2 Table skop

```
 ______________________________________________
 | id | noskom      | noskop     | price_skop |
 |____|_____________|____________|____________|
 |  1 | 1           |   1        |   10       |  
 |  2 | 1           |   2        |   20       |  
 |  3 | 2           |   3        |    5       | 
 |  4 | 2           |   4        |   30       |  
 |____|_____________|____________|____________|
```

3 Table npbm

```
 ___________________________________________________________
 | id | noskom      | noskop     | nonpbm     | price_npbm |
 |____|_____________|____________|____________|____________|
 |  1 | 1           |   1        |   1        |   10       | 
 |  2 | 1           |   1        |   2        |   20       |   
 |  3 | 1           |   2        |   3        |    5       | 
 |  4 | 1           |   2        |   4        |    5       | 
 |  5 | 2           |   1        |   5        |   10       |   
 |  6 | 2           |   2        |   6        |   10       |  
 |  7 | 2           |   2        |   7        |   10       |       
 |____|_____________|____________|____________|____________|
```

4 Table npbp

```
 ________________________________________________________________________
 | id | noskom      | noskop     | nonpbm     | nonpbp     | price_npbp |
 |____|_____________|____________|____________|____________|____________|
 |  1 | 1           |   1        |   1        |    1       |   10       | 
 |  2 | 1           |   1        |   2        |    2       |   20       |   
 |  3 | 1           |   2        |   3        |    3       |    5       | 
 |  4 | 1           |   2        |   4        |    4       |    5       | 
 |  5 | 2           |   1        |   5        |    5       |   10       |   
 |  6 | 2           |   2        |   6        |    6       |   10       |  
 |  7 | 2           |   2        |   7        |   10       |   10       |       
 |____|_____________|____________|____________|____________|____________|
```

and i need help for query like this

```
 select sum(price_skom),sum(price_skop),sum(price_npbm),sum(price_npbp) from each table group by noskom
```

i want result like this

TABLE RESULT GROUP BY noskom

```
 ________________________________________________________________
 | id | noskom      | sum_skom | sum_skop | sum_npbm | sum_npbp |
 |____|_____________|__________|__________|__________|__________|
 |  1 | 1           |   10     |   30     |    40    |   90     |  
 |  2 | 2           |   30     |   35     |    30    |   70     |      
 |__3_|_3___________|___50_____|__________|__________|__________|
```

Help me with mysql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select 
noskom, 
sum (pskom) as sum_skom, 
sum (pskop) as sum_skop, 
sum (pnpbm) as sum_npbm, 
sum (pnpbp) as sum_npbp

from
(
select noskom, sum (price_skom) as pskom, 0 as pskop, 0 as pnpbm, 0 as pnpbp from skom group by noskom
union all
select noskom, 0, sum (price_skop), 0, 0 from skop group by noskom
union all
select noskom, 0, 0, sum (price_npbm), 0 from npbm group by noskom
union all
select noskom, 0, 0, 0, sum (price_npbp) from npbp group by noskom
) as p

group by noskom
```

Comment: @AndiNugroho This is a common technique if you are dealing with multiple tables where joining them doesn't make logical sense. It may look inefficient but should result in a single full scan of each table followed by aggregation of the result sets. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To also get the rows with no corresponding noscom, you need to have a outer join:

```
select sk1.id, sk1.noskom,sum(price_skom),sum(price_skop),sum(price_npbm),sum(price_npbp) 
from skom sk1 left outer join skop on (sk1.id=skop.noskom),
     skom sk2 left outer join npbm on (sk2.id=npbm.noskom),
     skom sk3 left outer join npbp on (sk3.id=npbp.noskom)
Where sk1.id=sk2.id and sk2.id=sk3.id
group by  sk1.id,sk1.noskom
```